# OSError: [WinError 10057] Windows

Tags: python-3.x, socket

Últimamente, he estado creando un par de scripts (cliente y servidor) para crear una especie de "chat", basándose en sockets. En la línea 16 del servidor, si se recibe el mensaje *b''*, el servidor debería interpretar que el cliente quiere finalizar la conexión. Pero al recibir el mensaje, lanza la siguiente excepción:

```
OSError: [WinError 10057] No se permitió una solicitud para enviar o recibir datos ya que el socket no está conectado y no se ha proporcionado ninguna dirección, al realizar el envío en un socket de datagramas por medio de una llamada sendto
```

Aquí os dejo los scripts. Gracias de antemano.

SERVER

```
import socket

def serverStart():
    print("Creating socket server...", end="")
    s=socket.socket()
    print(" Done")
    print("Binding socket server...", end="")
    s.bind(('127.0.0.1', 9234))
    print(" Done")
    print("Starting to listen...", end="")
    s.listen(2)
    print(" Done")
    while True:
        conn, address=s.accept()
        msg = conn.recv(64)
        if msg!=b'':
            print(str(address) + " sent: " + str(msg))
        else:
            print("Connection closed.")
            s.shutdown(1)
            break
while True:
    serverStart()
```

CLIENT

```
import socket
try:
    def main():
        s=socket.socket()
        s.connect(("127.0.0.1", 9234))
        while True:
            s.send(bytes(input("Message to be sent: "), encoding="utf-8"))
            s.close()
            del(s)
            s=socket.socket()
            s.connect(("127.0.0.1", 9234))
    main()
except ConnectionResetError:
    print("Server has finished connection\n"
    "Connecting again...")
    main()
```

Comment: Puedes incluir el stacktrace completo? En que linea ocurre el error?